# running 2 excel versions at once, cant associate filetype to older version

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016, csv

I have excel 07 and the latest Excel 365 (I think thats Excel 16) both installed in windows 10. When I just had 07, I had no problem associating csv and xlsx files with that program. Now that I have installed the newer version, if I associate a csv or xlsx with 07 and I double click a file, I get this message:

This app can't run on your PC

To find a version for your PC, check the software publisher.
[image]
I can still open the file in 07 if I just open 07 first and open the file from there.

Is there any way to make this work?

The reason I have both is that I prefer 07 for my day to day, but occasionally need the newer version for making charts not available in 07.

Comment: I assume Office 2007 is 32-bit and Office 365 is 64-bit? How did you associate the file extension to Excel 2007?

Comment: @Ramhound correct

Comment: @Ramhound oh sorry, missed the 2nd part. I associated by right clicking the file, going to "Open With..." and then picking 07

Comment: Here are some recommendations [Office 2007 and Office 2013, 2016, or 2019 side by side](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-2007-and-office-2013-2016-or-2019-side-by-side-26418d8b-957e-4b4f-8c08-e18d0eae97ae). Pls see the section about File Associations and also Office 2007 Updates. If nothing works, you can create a new right-click menu that will open the document in Office 2007.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-check-with-the/93c9d14d-0000-42a3-8659-3d8ac41de08a Check if this suggestion is helpful.

Comment: @w32sh what I gleaned from the article is that it won't work if one is 32 bit and the other isn't, and also based on the article I guess I'm surprised I was able to even install mixed versions to begin with.

Comment: @chiliNUT : Noticed that. To prevent a file association clash between two versions, you can introduce a right-click menu option (via the registry) that says "Open with Office 2007" for .CSV files.

Comment: @w32sh do you have a description or a link to explain how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a context menu item to open these file types in Office 2007. Here's a registry file that adds the "Open with Excel 2007" context menu for .CSV files.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.CSV\shell\Open2]
@="Open with Excel 2007"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.CSV\shell\Open2\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\excel.exe\" \"%1\""

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.csv\UserChoice]
```

1. Copy the above contents to Notepad.
2. Save the file as `"csv.reg"`.
3. Double-click to run the file.
4. Click Yes when asked for confirmation.

After that, you should see "Open with Excel 2007" in the right-click menu.

[image]

**Edit:** FileExts key added, in case the override exists.

Comment: I had to tweak this a little, and then it worked great!

1. I had to remove the trailing `**` from the command.
2. I used types (https://ystr.github.io/types/) to make the 2ndary action this created to be the default, so now I can double click instead of using the context menu
Thanks!

Comment: The trailing `**` is not supposed to be included. It's a mistake I made when formatting that reply. :(